# Get new prototypes in singleton factory

Tags: java, spring, singleton, prototype, factory

I've created a type called `HelperFactory`. It's wired like this in the Spring context:

```
<bean id="HelperFactory" class="helper.HelperFactory">
    <property name="createHelper" ref="createHelperBean" />
    <property name="editHelper" ref="editHelperBean" />
    <property name="deleteHelper" ref="deleteHelperBean" />
</bean>
```

All the referenced beans are prototypes.

The `HelperFactory` has got a method called `determinteHelper(HelperDto)`. This method should return a new instance of the appropriate `Helper`.

But since the `HelperFactory` is a singleton, all referenced `Helper` are also set only once. How can I get a new `Helper` instance every time I call - say - `getCreateHelper()`?

---

Ther `Helper` beans are too declared in an XML context and have some other beans injected into them.

---

Currently I'm injecting the Bean's names into the `HelperFactory` and call then `getBean(String)`, but I'm looking for something better than this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we have done it on my project:

In the factory class, provide a method as such:

```
public Object createObject(){
      return null;
}
```

In your bean do the following:

```
<bean id="blah" class="blahblah">
    <lookup-method name="createObject" bean="myPrototypeBean"/>
</bean>
```

This will cause an override of the createObject method that returns the bean when the method is called. If the bean is a prototype bean, a new instance will be returned for each invokation.

Check out the `3.3.4.1. Lookup method Injection` section of [Spring Beans](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html)

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from Spring documentation:

When defining a bean which is to be created using a static factory method, along with the class attribute which specifies the class containing the static factory method, another attribute named factory-method is needed to specify the name of the factory method itself. Spring expects to be able to call this method (with an optional list of arguments as described later) and get back a live object, which from that point on is treated as if it had been created normally via a constructor. One use for such a bean definition is to call static factories in legacy code.

Following is an example of a bean definition which specifies that the bean is to be created by calling a factory-method. Note that the definition does not specify the type (class) of the returned object, only the class containing the factory method. In this example, createInstance must be a static method.

```
  <bean id="exampleBean"
      class="examples.ExampleBean2"
      factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

Comment: My prototype beans are declared in an XML context and have some dependencies injected into them.